# SQL Trigger - How do I test for the operation?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2000

My trigger fires on `INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE`.  I need to insert from the appropriate in memory table (`inserted, deleted`) depending upon which operation triggered the trigger.  Since only `inserted` is populated on `INSERT` or `deleted` on `DELETE` I figure I can just do an insert and if there's no rows and I'm good.

But, `UPDATE` populates both tables.  I only want the values from `deleted` on `UPDATE`.  I tried testing for update using `UPDATE(column)` function, but this returns `TRUE` even on `INSERT`.  So, how can I test for `UPDATE`?

```
ALTER TRIGGER CREATE_tableAudit
   ON dbo.table
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN          
    IF(UPDATE([column1]))--returns true on INSERT :(
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableAudit]
               ([column1]
               ,[CreateDate]
               ,[UpdateDate])
               SELECT * from deleted --update
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        --only inserted is populated on INSERT, visa-versa with DELETE
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableAudit]
               ([column1]
               ,[CreateDate]
               ,[UpdateDate])
               select * from inserted --insert


        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableAudit]
               ([column1]
               ,[CreateDate]
               ,[UpdateDate])
               select * from deleted --delete

        END
```

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off having three separate triggers - one for each operation.

Comment: @marc_s - maybe so.  I try to be as DRY as possible.  In this case I will just move UPDATE out to simplify things.  I thought this would be easier than it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the primary keys of rows didn't change, you can find updated rows by joining the Inserted and Deleted tables on the primary key field(s). If joining these two tables produces rows, then you can safely assume that those rows were updated.

If an update does change the primary key of a row, then you're probably better off just treating it as two operations, a delete and an insert.

Answer (score 3):

To test for UPDATE, look for identical primary key values in both the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables.

```
/* These rows have been updated */
SELECT i.PKColumn
    FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN deleted d
            ON i.PKColumn = d.PKColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

The following has been useful to in triggers:
The * in the queries could be changed to include only fields you want to have compared; could exclude the autonumber if it changes in the source table.

To check for Inserted:

```
if exists (Select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted)
begin
   ...
end
```

To check for Updated:

```
if exists(SELECT * from inserted) and exists (SELECT * from deleted) 
begin
   ...
end
```

To check for Deleted:

```
if exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(Select * from inserted)
begin
   ...
end
```

Comment: This helped me clear my confusion on previous and new values as a part of the audit. Thank you